# Is it possible to disable open with Chrome the dynamic link?

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I use Firebase Dynamic Links. When I click on the link on my Android device, it'll ask which app I'd like to open with: Chrome(browser) or the app which handles the links. Is it possible to disable to open these links with chrome and instantly open the app?

I followed these instructions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly on the settings of your phone. If you choose to open the link directly to your app and set it "Always Open" then it will not ask if you would like this to be opened in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this trouble in my application also so I did a little research and put an intent filter in my `AndroidManifest.xml` and Now when I click on the dynamic link android system ask to choose Application to open the link, there you can set your app as default for that link and the future links will directly open in your app without going to any browser.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with YOUR_SCHEME://YOUR_HOST -->
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"//this one is scheme
                    android:host=[HOSTNAME]// this is host name for eg: app.page.link
 />
            </intent-filter>
```

What this does is, it tells the system that this app can handle URLs with `https` scheme and `HOSTNAME` .

I have tested this on few mobiles phone and this is an android only integration. I don't know about iOS